# gcc sizeof float _Imaginary

Tags: c

I am attempting to get the byte storage size of gcc data types. The program I am using is listed below.

```
// limits.c
// show data type storage size in bytes
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <limits.h>

  int main(int argc, char* args[]) {
        printf("         Type          Bytes\n");
        printf("  ---------------------------\n");
        printf("  char................... %d \n",   sizeof(char));
        printf("  unsigned char.......... %d \n",   sizeof(unsigned char));
        printf("  signed char............ %d \n\n", sizeof(signed char ));

        printf("  int.................... %d \n",   sizeof(int));
        printf("  unsigned int........... %d \n",   sizeof(unsigned int));
        printf("  signed int............. %d \n\n", sizeof(signed int));

        printf("  short.................. %d \n",   sizeof(short ));
        printf("  unsigned short......... %d \n",   sizeof(unsigned short));
        printf("  signed short........... %d \n\n", sizeof(signed short));

        printf("  long................... %d \n",   sizeof(long ));
        printf("  unsigned long.......... %d \n",   sizeof(unsigned long));
        printf("  signed long............ %d \n\n", sizeof(signed long));

        printf("  long................... %d \n",   sizeof(long long));
        printf("  unsigned long.......... %d \n",   sizeof(unsigned long long));
        printf("  signed long............ %d \n\n", sizeof(signed long long));

        printf("  float _Complex......... %d \n",   sizeof(float _Complex));          
        printf("  double _Complex........ %d \n",   sizeof(double _Complex));       
        printf("  long double _Complex... %d \n\n", sizeof(long double _Complex));  

//    printf("  float _Imaginary....... %d \n",   sizeof(float _Imaginary));         
//    printf("  double _Imaginary...... %d \n",   sizeof(double _Imaginary));     
//    printf("  long double _Imaginary. %d \n",   sizeof(long double _Imaginary));

        printf("  Press any key to exit...");
        getchar();
        return 0;
  }
```

The code works except for my attempt to get the size of ***_Imaginary*** data types (which I have commented out to make sure the program is running properly). I am using *"gcc -std=gnu99 -o %OUT% %SRC%"* which should force C99 compliance. What must I do to get this sizeof to work?

Comment: `printf` `%d` takes `int`, not `size_t`. All your printf calls have undefined behavior.

Comment: *"All your printf calls have undefined behavior"*, the use of %d was a snippet from a book and works (provides correct answers).

Comment: Then that book was a bad book. Code appearing to "work" is one of the possible manifestations of undefined behavior. That doesn't mean it's correct.

Comment: ... use the correct format specifier for `size_t`, which is `%zu`.

Comment: `size_t` should either be printed using `%zu`, or it can casted to `int` when using `%d` (although this can truncate the value depending on the processor architecture).

Comment: @contrapants What truncation? Do you really have core types whose size exceeds 32k bytes?

Comment: @melpomene It's more about the principle than actual values.

Comment: It's possible for `size_t` to be different number of bytes than `int`, especially in embedded systems.

Comment: @contrapants Yes, but the actual values here are the sizes of `char`, `int`, `long`, etc. I'm pretty sure those are going to fit in an `int`.

Comment: The type `_Complex` is defined in `complex.h` (you need to include the math library with `-lm` if you work with GCC)

Comment: @deamentiaemundi `_Complex` is a keyword and part of the language.

Comment: @melpomene that's nice but doesn't help with GCC

Comment: @deamentiaemundi GCC has nothing to do with it. `_Complex` is not defined in `<complex.h>`.

Comment: @melpomene it's not`_Complex` I was thinking about but `complex`. Argh! Brainfart, sorry.

Comment: Well,, with that sorted out, anybody have any idea how to get *"printf("  float _Imaginary....... %zu \n",   sizeof(float _Imaginary));"* to work?

Comment: main.c:32:62: error: expected ')' before '_Imaginary'

Comment: If your question is about `_Imaginary`, why do you have all that other code in there and why is the only relevant part commented out? And the error message should be part of your question, not down here hidden in the comments.

Comment: You have already given the question a -1. Since you don't think it has merit why do you keep participating and finding fault? Why not let someone interested answer it.

Comment: Since I don't think *it is as clear as it could be*, I keep participating and *suggesting ways to improve it*. You might also want to read [mcve]. "*"It doesn't work" is not a problem statement*", etc.

Comment: I haven't found anything explicitly mentioned in the documentation yet, but I strongly suspect that gcc doesn't support `_Imaginary`. There's no alias for `imaginary` in `<complex.h>` or any other use of the keyword that I can see. (And clang 6.0 explicitly says it doesn't support `_Imaginary`, fwiw)

Comment: @shawn - that seems to be a possibility. C99 added it but the gcc docs say it will default to C99 when "finished". I assume that after 18 years they had it working.

Comment: Ah, found it. https://gcc.gnu.org/c99status.html - standalone imaginary numbers are apparently optional in C99 and not supported by gcc.

Comment: This compiles and runs for me using GCC. My compilers are `gcc (tdm64-1) 5.1.0` on Windows and `gcc (Gentoo 7.3.0-r3 p1.4) 7.3.0` on Linux.

Comment: ["*The default, if no C language dialect options are given, is -std=gnu11.*"](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Standards.html#C-Language) We're way past C99 now.

Comment: @contrapants - I am using C:\MinGW\bin\gcc -o %OUT% %SRC% what are you using?

Comment: I specified `-std=gnu99` as the question specified, although not passing in a `-std` flag also worked.

Comment: @jwzumwalt I'm using TDM-GCC-64.

Comment: Is there a gcc switch I can use to see what version I have? I found a unix "info gcc" but I am on win.

Comment: `gcc --version`. `info` is just a documentation browser.

Comment: I also just tested using the MinGW 4.92_32 installation that comes with Qt 5.5.0 on Windows. It also worked.

Comment: gcc reports "2018 posix-seh 8.1.0". I wonder if posix is causing me problems?

Comment: Ignore me, everybody. It failed for me, too. I forgot to uncomment the lines when I pasted the code into my VMs. I'm sorry.

Comment: @contrapants Not your fault; OP should have provided a [mcve] in the first place.

Comment: Aside: For completeness of core types, consider `_Bool`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're getting syntax errors because gcc does not implement `_Imaginary`:

From the [gcc c99 status page](https://gcc.gnu.org/c99status.html):

> GCC does not support the Annex G imaginary types, but this support is optional ...

Quoting from [cppreference on _Imaginary_I](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/complex/Imaginary_I):

> A compiler that defines `__STDC_IEC_559_COMPLEX__` is not required to support imaginary numbers. POSIX recommends checking if the macro `_Imaginary_I` is defined to identify imaginary number support. (since C99) (until C11)
>
> Imaginary numbers are supported if `__STDC_IEC_559_COMPLEX__` is defined. (since C11)

The original question uses C99, but gcc also defines `__STDC_IEC_559_COMPLEX__` in C11 mode even though it doesn't support `_Imaginary`, which is kind of annoying and sounds like a violation of the standard.

Comment: Defining `__STDC_IEC_559_COMPLEX__` in C11 mode is a simple bug (someone didn't notice that imaginary types became mandatory for Annex G support in C11); please file a report at https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/ .

Comment: [This bugzilla thread](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=15720) argues that it's not a bug, that you just aren't supposed to trust GCC when it declares this macro. (I'm not saying I agree with this, just pointing this out.)